# How to determine partition key/column with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I use `partitionBy` to save some data to disk, e.g. by date so my data looks like this:

```
/mydata/d=01-01-2018/part-00000
/mydata/d=01-01-2018/part-00001
...
/mydata/d=02-01-2018/part-00000
/mydata/d=02-01-2018/part-00001
...
```

When I read the data using Hive config and `DataFrame`, so

```
val df = sparkSession.sql(s"select * from $database.$tableName")
```

I can know that:

- Filter queries on column `d` will push down
- No shuffles will occur if I try to partition by `d` (e.g. `GROUP BY d`)

BUT, suppose I don't know what the partition key is (some upstream job writes the data, and has no conventions).  How can I get Spark to tell me which is the partition key, in this case `d`.  Similarly if we have multiple partitions (e.g. by month, week, then day).

Currently the best code we have is really ugly:

```
def getPartitionColumnsForHiveTable(databaseTableName: String)(implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): Set[String] = {
    val cols = sparkSession.
      sql(s"desc $databaseTableName")
      .select("col_name")
      .collect
      .map(_.getAs[String](0))
      .dropWhile(r => !r.matches("# col_name"))
    if (cols.isEmpty) {
      Set()
    } else {
      cols.tail.toSet
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure no shuffles will occur in this case? I thought only bucketed hive tables have this behavior?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I might be out of date, Spark changes the way files are read into partitions seemingly on every release (so what was once true isn't always true).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't have `=` and `/` in your partitioned column values, you can do:

```
val df = spark.sql("show partitions database.test_table")

val partitionedCols: Set[String] = try { 
  df.map(_.getAs[String](0)).first.split('/').map(_.split("=")(0)).toSet
} catch {
  case e: AnalysisException => Set.empty[String]
}
```

You should get an `Array[String]` with the partitioned column names.

Comment: Certainly less code yes. Still a bit dirty with all the string manip.

Comment: Also, this approach (a) relies on data actually existing in the table and (b) if there are no partitioning then it throws exception (so needs some extra code to handle, I will edit).

Comment: this does not work (spark 2.3) : `error: not enough arguments for method collect: (pf: PartialFunction[String,B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[String],B,That])That.
Unspecified value parameter pf.`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth `collect` is not needed since `first` is being used. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @philantrovert what if `.partitionBy` was not used, but rather `.repartition(N, *cols)`? I.e. no hive-style subdirectory structure.

Answer (score 2):

you can use sql statements to get this info, either `show create table <tablename>`, `describe extended <tablename>` or `show partitions <tablename>`. The last one gives the simplest output to parse:

```
val partitionCols = spark.sql("show partitions <tablename>").as[String].first.split('/').map(_.split("=").head)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the metadata to get the partition column names in a comma-separated string.
First check if the table is partitioned, if true get the partition columns

```
val table = "default.country"

def isTablePartitioned(spark:org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, table:String) :Boolean = {
    val col_details = spark.sql(s" describe extended ${table} ").select("col_name").select(collect_list(col("col_name"))).as[Array[String]].first
    col_details.filter( x => x.contains("# Partition Information" )).length > 0
}


def getPartitionColumns(spark:org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, table:String): String = {
    val pat =  """(?ms)^\s*#( Partition Information)(.+)(Detailed Table Information)\s*$""".r
    val col_details = spark.sql(s" describe extended ${table} ").select("col_name").select(collect_list(col("col_name"))).as[Array[String]].first
    val col_details2 = col_details.filter( _.trim.length > 0 ).mkString("\n")
    val arr = pat.findAllIn(col_details2).matchData.collect{ case pat(a,b,c) => b }.toList(0).split("\n").filterNot( x => x.contains("#") ).filter( _.length > 0 )
    arr.mkString(",")
}

if( isTablePartitioned(spark,table) ) 
 { 
    getPartitionColumns(spark,table) 
 } 
 else 
 { 
    "--NO_PARTITIONS--" 
 }
```

Note: The other 2 answers assume the table to have data which will fail, if the table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner. When no partitions are present the spark call throws an AnalysisException (SHOW PARTITIONS is not allowed on a table that is not partitioned). I'm handling that with the scala.util.Try, but his could be improved catching the correct type of exception.

```
def getPartitionColumns(table: String) = scala.util.Try(spark.sql(s"show partitions $table").columns.toSeq).getOrElse(Seq.empty)
```