# How to identify the partition columns in hive table using Spark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to identify the partition Column names in a hive table using Spark .I am able to do that using show partitions followed by parsing the resultset to extract the partition columns .However , the drawback is , if some of the tales do not have a partition in them , the show partition fails .Is there a more organic way to identify the partition column names in a hive table.
Any help would be highly appreciated

```
v_query="show partitions {}".format(table_name)
a=self.spark.sql(v_query)
val=a.rdd.map(list).first()
val1=''.join(val)
partition_list=[l.split('=')[0] for l in val1.split('/')]
```

Comment: you are doing it right. The following link provides a more robust code to handle this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148208/how-to-determine-partition-key-column-with-spark

Comment: I do not want to do show partitions .That was the main part i was trying to avoid .There might be non partiitioned tables and this would fail for them

Answer (score 3):

Above code will fail incase table is not partitioned. It will give you an error message like `"pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'SHOW PARTITIONS is not allowed on a table that is not partitioned"`

you can use map operation on `desc` command to get the partition column information.

```
>>> spark.sql("""desc db.newpartitiontable""").show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+---------+-------+
|col_name               |data_type|comment|
+-----------------------+---------+-------+
|city                   |string   |null   |
|state                  |string   |null   |
|country                |string   |null   |
|tran_date              |string   |null   |
|# Partition Information|         |       |
|# col_name             |data_type|comment|
|tran_date              |string   |null   |
+-----------------------+---------+-------+

partition_exists=spark.sql("""desc db.newpartitiontable""").rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).filter(lambda x: x.startswith("# col_name")).collect()

if len(partition_exists)>0:
    print("table is partitioned")
    partition_col=spark.sql("""show partitions test_dev_db.newpartitiontable""").rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).map(lambda x : [l.split('=')[0] for l in x.split('/')]).first()
    print("Partition column is:",partition_col)
else:
    print("table is not partitioned")
```

Comment: Thansk Vikrant .It looks good .However , can we avoid the show partitions and somehow directory parse the partition column name from the describe table?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. I have answered similar thing on another question. Please check.

Comment: Can you please provide the link

Comment: Here's the link and it seems that that question was raised by you only.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011003/identify-partition-key-column-from-a-table-using-pyspark/58121166#58121166

Answer (score 1):

How to get an array of partition columns in Scala/Spark:

```
spark.catalog.listColumns(fullTableName)
    .where(col("ispartition"))
    .select("name")
    .collect()
    .map(_.getAs[String]("name"))
```

Feel free to change the above code to work with PySpark.