# How to retrieve partition columns from Glue Catalog table programmatically using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a table called demo and it is cataloged in Glue. The table has three partition columns (col_year, col_month and col_day). I want to get the name of the partition columns programmatically using pyspark. The output should be below with the partition values (just the partition keys)

col_year, col_month, col_day

Could you please help me in getting the desired output? Thank you

Comment: You can use spark. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148208/how-to-determine-partition-key-column-with-spark